# HTTP redirect without 302

Tags: http, redirect, networking

Hello I am analyzing the network flow between two host and the client and there is a “jump” i can not understand how it was done.
The first request it is done to server A.
The server A respondes with a 302 status and a location response header to server B, the location url is http:B.com?urlAPP=A.The host B respondes with status 200 and I do not know why after this a new request is done again to server A. I know that we send in the location url the urlAPP to the site B call again the A , but the response of the B server is not a redirect and there is not any payload in the B response(some kind of JS who make the new request to host A)
Do you have any idea of how A got called again ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to figure this out by using the DevTools within the Chrome Browser. Within the network tab you can enable "Preserve log", within the request table you can add an additional column "Initiator". By hovering over the initiator column you should see how the redirect was initiated.